# Updating last entry in OleDbCommand with the same ID

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access

I'm trying to Update the last entry in a table called "Building_Login" I want the last entry of a certain ID (which isn't unique) to be updated but every time I attempt to do this it updates all the ID's that equal my query, I only want the last one updated however.

I'm currently trying to get TOP 1 working as Limit 1 doesn't seem to work with my Access Database.

```
OleDbCommand commandUpdate = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Building_Login] SET Exited = '" + DateTime.Now + "' WHERE TOP 1 User_ID = @UserID ORDER BY User_ID DESC", connection);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The first suggestion I can give is to stop using string concatenation to put data into your query.

Comment: Also: what is full the primary key of the table?

Comment: Only reason I used string concatenation for DateTime.Now was because Parameters.AddWithValue parsed the DateTime.Now and caused a SQL error. This table has no primary key, it's only for logging data, perhaps the wisest option would be to create an auto increment primary key field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I've found, it is messy but it does the job for now, I select the latest DateTime from my table as means of ordering it to get the latest result for the given userID.

```
OleDbCommand commandUpdate = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Building_Login] SET Exited = '" + DateTime.Now + "' WHERE User_ID = @UserId AND Entered = (SELECT Top 1 Entered AS latest FROM [Building_Login] WHERE User_ID = @UserId ORDER BY Entered DESC)", connection);
```